# How to get the input text from the input element in a Blazor app?

Tags: c#, input, blazor, local-storage

I am basically trying to get the input text and save it to the local storage and in a users list with the data model DataModel,I am writing this in a Blazor WebAssembly App.
I am trying to get the input text from the input field,and save it to the local storage and add the id to the list users.
This is Written in the Index.razor page.

```
 Index.razor page

  <EditForm Model="@_loginData" OnSubmit="HandleLogin" class="login-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ID" name="psw" id="psw" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" form="form" required>
  

    @if(errorMessage)
    {
        <div class="mb-3">
            <h5 style="color: red">You Are Already Logged In.You Are going to be redirected to the Alert Page in a second.</h5>
        </div>
    }
  
           <button type="submit" class="loginlink">Log in</button>
   
</EditForm>

private DataModel data = new DataModel();

private List<string> users = new List<string>();

string smstext = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 4);


public class DataModel
 {

     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string UserId { get; set; }

     public string SMSCode { get; set; }

     public string Token { get; set; }
   
 }

 private async void HandleLogin()
 {

     var currentId = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("id");

     if(currentId!=null)
     {
         var user = users.Contains(currentId);

         Console.WriteLine(currentId);

         Console.WriteLine(users);

         await Task.Delay(1700);
         errorMessage = true;
         NavManager.NavigateTo("/products")
     }
     else 
     {  
         Random rnd = new Random();
         int num = rnd.Next(1);

         var randomId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<int>("id", num);
         await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("userId", randomId);
         await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

         NavManager.NavigateTo("/yourpage");

     }
```

Comment: Could you please give us the code you actually use? I understand that you are trying to combine things for the sake of ease, but we need to be able to reproduce what you are trying to do. But why dont you simply use @bind?

Comment: Hello, I added some more code it helps,I am new to this type of applications I am not sure how to use it.